# Why executable throws error after cloning from Git repository?

Tags: python-3.x, git, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I started using *Git* recently and I wanted to share my small project. It is a simple decimal conversion program written in *Python3*. I also coded the GUI using *tkinter* module.

I want the end-user to run the program as an **executable**. So I made my .py source file to an executable using `pyinstaller`. The executable worked perfectly.

I then created a [new repository](https://github.com/maddypie/Bin2Dec) in Git and uploaded my source file and other files created by `pyinstaller` [build, dist, .spec]. When I tried cloning my repository. the executable throws an **error** saying:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Also, is this even the correct way of distributing an open source software?

Comment: What flags did you use?

Comment: @Saad What are flags?

Comment: Like `--onedir`, `--noconsole`, check [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) aka arguments.

Comment: I used ```--onefile```